# Java class runs fine in IntelliJ but not from command line

Tags: command-line, java

I've compiled and run a simple Java file in IntelliJ. It contains a main method and one other small static method. It works perfectly every time.

However, whenever I try to run the `java` command on the `.class` file from the terminal I get this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class *[file name here]*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You have to run `java YourClassName`, not `java YourClassName.class`.

The problem is that you are including the `.class` suffix in the command.

<sup>There are a few other possible explanations, since you have not given the specific command you ran. It's possible that you are running the command from somewhere other than the location of your `.class` file and not giving a full path to it, or that you are misspelling its name, and so forth. However, including a spurious `.class` suffix, which the `java` command does not expect, is the most common cause of this problem.</sup>

Suppose the class that contains your program's entry point (`main()` method) is called `Foo`, and that its source code was in a file in the current directory called `Foo.java`, so that you compiled your program by running `javac Foo.java`. Because `Foo` is the name of the class, this produces a file called `Foo.class` containing the compiled Java bytecode for that class.

To run the program, you must run:

```
java Foo
```

Your description makes it sound like you are instead running `java Foo.class`. This is a common stumbling block for users who using the `java` command to run `.class` files for the first time (whether they are programming in Java or just running `.class` files provided by someone else).

`java Foo.class` won't work; the `java` command interprets its argument as the name of the class that contains the entry point, *not* the name of the file. When you run `java Foo` it knows to look for a file called `Foo.class`.